# Trying to authenticate user in postman - getting a "403 Forbidden"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

So, I am following a tutorial from a book, on how to implement user authentification via spring security. Its pretty basic but something is not working. It is the same code as my colleague's, but mine is not working strangely. I would be very thankful for every help in this case. I am using Kotlin.

So I have 2 classes in my backend:

AuthorizationServerConfig.kt:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class AuthorizationServerConfig(private val userDetailService: UserDetailsService, private val 
         authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager): AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(clients: ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer){
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("mycompany")
                .secret("thisissecret")
                .authorities("USER","ADMIN")
                .scopes("all")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password","client_credentials")
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(endpoints: AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer?) {
        super.configure(endpoints)
        endpoints?.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            ?.userDetailsService(userDetailService)
    }

 }
```

The second class, SecurityConfig.kt:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
class SecurityConfig(): WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(){

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder){

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("123456").roles("USER")
            .and()
            .withUser("admin").password("123456").roles("USER", "ADMIN")
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity){
         http.authorizeRequests()
             .anyRequest()
             .authenticated()
    }

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun userDetailsServiceBean(): UserDetailsService {
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean()
    }

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun authenticationManagerBean(): AuthenticationManager {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean()
    }

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    @Bean
    open fun passwordEncoder(): NoOpPasswordEncoder {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance() as NoOpPasswordEncoder
    }
}
```

Dependencies are all implemented.

**Note**: The code is working on my colleagues pc. I am just using his code.

What am I doing from here?

I want to authenticate via Postman. This is what I am trying:

[image]

I also have this in the body:

[image]

But, clicking on 'Send', I am getting a `403 Forbidden`. I dont know what I did wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction and also explain what I did wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you try passing only one grant_type i.e  password.

You can clone this git repo, t is having almost same code that you are trying, it works.

https://github.com/cvillaseca/mobileAPI/tree/part2

Also not sure, why you are appending v1 after port, is it api root context?

Comment: Thank you, but not necessaary anymore. The problem was the v1 you just mentioned. When I removed `v1` and `auth` from the path, it worked.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: @Mahesh_Loya Do you mind watching over my recent post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64679097/spring-security-returning-anonymous-user-after-successful-authenticaiton

Comment: Sure.Please check  respective post.