# Spring Security returning anonymous user after successful authenticaiton

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I am new to Spring Security and want to get the username of the current user. The authentication works so far but when trying to get the current username of user, I am getting an `anonymousUser`.

I am using Kotlin.

This is what I am trying:

SecurityConfig.kt:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
class SecurityConfig(): WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(){

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder){

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("123456").roles("USER")
            .and()
            .withUser("admin").password("123456").roles("USER", "ADMIN")
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity){ 

        http.authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("v1/mobile/**")
           .authenticated().and().httpBasic()
    }

...
}
```

AuthorizationServerConfig.kt:

```
//class header not shown here

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(clients: ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer){
        clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient("spiritdev")
            .secret("thisissecret")
            .authorities("USER","ADMIN")
            .scopes("all")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password","client_credentials")
    }
```

First I authenticate in Postman like this:

[image]

This works good. But when using a method like `http://localhost:8080/v1/mobile/tickets`, which logs the current username (code below):

```
var currentPrincipalName: String? = 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication.principal.toString()

logger.info { "currentPrincipalName!" }
logger.info { currentPrincipalName }
```

the output says `anonymousUser`.

I don't understand why. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? Thanks for every help!

Comment: `httpBasic()` is not oauth2 and tokens. When you want to access a protected endpoint you have to send the username and password, base64 encoded in a `Authorization` header. For example `Authorization: Basic Zm9vYmFyOnBhc3N3b3JkMTIz` and you get a cookie back that you need to include everytime you talk to an endpoint.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf yeah yeah, thats what I am doing. I get a Bearer token back and send it in the following request via the header, using `Authorization` as key and `Bearer myToken` as value.

Comment: but your picture from postman tells me you are posting grant_type? and username and password to a token endpoint? none of the code you have provided has any oauth2 stuff in it, and spring security does not include a token issuer, if you are using oauth2 then where is the oauth2 code? It looks to me like you are mixing up oauth2 and basic auth.

Comment: 3 years have passed since I just asked that question....in 3 years so much changed in my life, and I guess in yours too. Isnt that crazy? I hope you, dear reader, are doing well and dont forget to care for your health and your aswell as your familiy's wellbeing!

Answer (score 0):

Lets try disabling anonymous auth -

```
http .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("v1/mobile/**")
            .authenticated().and().httpBasic()
```

I am assuming you are using right token as autorization header received in response of auth token endpoint request, as seen in screen shot.

Comment: what will this do?

Comment: I simply need to get the username of the currently authenticated user

Comment: The authenticated method is not found

Comment: @IonicMan Thanks for downvote. I have updated my answer. It is taking anonymous auth. Hence wanted to disable it and see if principal gives you required.

Comment: Let me know if it works. I will suggest going through this git repo and run entire code in step by step debug mode. You can set your debug point  on filters. This way you will learn each and every step that happen when a request is sent to your code.
https://github.com/cvillaseca/mobileAPI